# What is asymptotic complexity of Integer's multiplication in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I am interested in asymptotic complexities of multiplication operations for `int` type, `Integer` and `BigInteger` objects:

```
int i,j = <value>;
i * j; // O?
Integer i,j = new Integer(<value>);  
i * j; // O?
BigInteger i,j = new BigInteger(<value>);
i.multiply(j); //O?
```

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions) are the simple cases.

Comment: Um, `int` and `Integer` are O(1).  There is no n to worry about.  Multiplication is a single CPU instruction.

Comment: The answer you accepted from me was out of date. I updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigInteger.multiply` uses multiple algorithms, depending on the size of the number.

Small numbers use [naive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) algorithm O(n^2)

Larger numbers use [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) algorithm O(n^1.585)

Largest numbers use [Toom–Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication) algorithm O(n^1.465)

I could not easily determine the threshold of the length of the number used to determine which algorithm to use. Please edit my answer if you know this.

`int` multiplication is `O(1)` because the size of the integer (n) is a constant value

Comment: This article is from 2011. Are you sure the algorithm wasn't improved in new releases of Java?

Comment: Good point. After looking at the source code it appears they have set threshold values for the size of the multiplicands, above which a different algorithm will be used. I will update my answer